Copy large file from remote machine, with only RDP access, to Azure blob storage
I need to copy a very large file (many 10s of GB) from a remote machine to which I have only RDP access.
The machine is accessible from VMs in my Azure environment and I can RDP normally.
I have been researching "azcopy" for this purpose, but so far I haven't found a scenario that would work.
Any ideas?

Can the machine in question access the internet at all, or is it well and truly isolated other than remote desktop? And when you say it's accessible from your VMs, what kind of access is that? Also RDP?

@RobM It has full access to the Internet, to the extent that I've so far verified. Some stuff/ports might well be blocked though. Sadly I only have RDP access from my machines and no way to punch the necessary holes for SFTP to work.

I would be looking into making an outgoing connection, rsync over ssh or something like that, what OS are you running?

@RobM Everything is Windows. I'm going to install azcopy and run with that.
